# Simple scrollX element with scroll snap, Changing page numbers

Tags: javascript, scroll, pagination

I'm trying to create simple element with scroll snapping. I've created a [demo in Codepen](https://codepen.io/stepanprucha/pen/abpvRdK).

I would like to scroll to an other image and after scroll, when other image is visible, change page number and the color of bottom circles.

I've tried to put onscroll"function()" in div .container and calculate somehow winW & scrollX ratios, but this approach is buggy and messy.

How should I make it, please? Thanks a lot.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: none;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.pagination {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  background: #777;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex: none;
}

#image-1 {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/fMp05Jf/tamanna-rumee-ov-U2t-Rgfj-H8-unsplash.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  beckground-position: center;
}

#image-2 {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/Fx3Vm0S/pranav-madhu-KHD8vyputcg-unsplash.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  beckground-position: center;
}

#image-3 {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/4Fznzvs/tijana-drndarski-cj-Es-Ho-Pk-ZOQ-unsplash.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  beckground-position: center;
}

#image-4 {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/bPWXGfR/kristaps-ungurs-trs-Gn-MDb-T2-E-unsplash.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  beckground-position: center;
}

#image-5 {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/5jyBdGK/joanna-kosinska-pj-Pe-CRkl83-M-unsplash.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  beckground-position: center;
}

.pills {
  padding: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle {
  margin: 8px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
}

#circle-1 {
  background: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="container x mandatory-scroll-snapping"">
  <div class="pagination">1 / 5</div>
  <div class="image" id="image-1"></div>
  <div class="image" id="image-2"></div>
  <div class="image" id="image-3"></div>
  <div class="image" id="image-4"></div>
  <div class="image" id="image-5"></div>
</div>
<div class="pills">
  <div class="circle" id="circle-1"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="circle-2"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="circle-3"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="circle-4"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="circle-5"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add anchor tags with the ID name of the slide to automatically scroll to them:

pills (with anchor tag)

```
<div class="pills">
 <a href="#image-3">
  <div class="circle" id="circle-1"></div>
 </a>
</div>
```